# XAMPP is displaying parent directory

Tags: windows, xampp, windows-server-2008

I installed XAMPP on my Windows 2008 server and created a new folder in the `HTDOCS` folder and the user can access the pages using the link.

For example:

```
http://1.1.20.305/MyDB/index.php
```

Will take the user to the `index.php` page.

But if I enter the following in my browser:

```
http://1.1.20.305/MyDB/
```

It displays the parent directory with all the files.

It is a security risk and how do I prevent it from happening? It should auto-route user to the index page or somewhere I define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file in the directory and the directory is not shown anymore.